# Error on "Updates and other software" when trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 desktop

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 20.04, windows-10

Screnshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj5Ah.jpg

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu alongside my windows 10 on an Asus K55VM (i7 and 8 GB of memory)
Laptop spec sheet: https://www.asus.com/Laptops/K55VM/specifications/

I've seen the error I'm getting a few times here mainly on 18.04, but non of the solutions have worked for me.

I thought i might had to do with the windows partitons like other posts here, but I can't unmount them since terminal just says they are not mounted.

I've tried two different USB's, with and without safe graphics mode and with and without network connection.

I'm trying to do a normal install shown in screenshot 2 and every time I get the two error boxes shown in screnshot 3 and 4.

I will say that the drive is the same 8 year old drive the laptop came with, and when trying to shrink a partition in windows it did act kind of strange where it wouldn't let me so I ended up deleting the whole partiton.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I ended up getting an SSD and after installing that I managed to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu